# need help - actionscript 3 simple button class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, button

I have very simple class, but it doesn't work? What could be wrong with this?

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import fl.controls.Button;

public class t_class extends Sprite {
    private var b:Button;

    public function t_class():void{
        b = new Button(); 
        b.width = 150;
        b.label = "button label";
        b.move(10, 150);
        b.enabled = false;
        addChild(b);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you ever add an instance of t_class to the stage?

Comment: yep, like this:
import t_class;
var bb = new t_class();
and tried like that:
import t_class;
new t_class();
nothing....

Comment: What @JoeTuskan asked was if you also added the instance of t_class to the display list, like this: `addChild(bb);`

Comment: can you please explain a little more your problem? what happens exactly?
Juste notice that the fl package is not used by flash, you must use an external swc to use the Button class

Comment: @gropapa I get no errors during compile, but button isn't created.

Comment: omg! I saw my mistake, and this one is stupid even for beginner... Thank's for everybody and specially for @JoeTuskan for addChild(bb)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are adding an instance of your button class as a child to the stage as others have mentioned above:

```
package
{
     //Imports
     import flash.display.Sprite;
     import com.wherever.is.t_class;

     //Class
     public class DocumentClass extends Sprite
     {
          //Constructor
          public function DocumentClass()
          {
               var myButton:t_class = new t_class();
               addChild(myButton);
          }
     }
}
```

The good news is that your t_class code is correct (minus a few deviations from AS3 code conventions, but i digress).  However, in order to use Flash Components they must be physically imported into the library in addition to being imported with code.  If they are not present in the library then Flash doesn't know they exist and you will receive the following during compile:

"***ERROR 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Button.***"

Goto *Window > Components*, select *User Interface > Button* and drag the component into your library.  Rebuild and you should see your button.

Comment: I have already imported button component into library, and I don't get any error message during compile. The problem is that button isn't created, so i'm here to solve this trully simple problem :)